# Is there a better way to write output of background tasks to the database?

Tags: python, django, database, azure, azure-webjobs

first of all thx for reading.

In my project, I have azure-function / azure webjob to do the parsing，analysis of the raw data when it comes to the storage account. The output will be update to database with direct sql command like:

```
sql_update = """UPDATE "PrototypeOne" SET files_amount =%s, used_time = %s where "User_Name" =%s;"""
cursor.execute(sql_update,vars)
```

My questions are:
1, is there a smarter way to update the database? can my backend play some role in between?

2, Is there a pub/sub library for such 'script level' application?

Background: My backend is django 2.0+, with postgresql as database on azure.

Comment: I get nervous when I see `%s` in a SQL statement, looks like it's ripe for SQL Injection.

Comment: hi Mark, thx for the comment. Can you help to recommend a better way to interact with db?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't done db work with Python. I was hoping someone would either tell me I'm worrying for nothing, or confirm that it's a problem. Either way I don't think it has much to do with your question.

Comment: no problem. Let's see, I look forward for a decent way to handle it, too

Comment: Do you mean some ORM framework for Python like [`SQLAlchemy`](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/)? And I don't understand about your 2nd question what the purpose is.

Comment: hi Peter, yes, the SQLAlchemy is exactly what I am look for, I have just checked the docu, and it makes the 2nd question kind of redundant. 
Thanks a lot for the recommendation.